# How to rotate the data_label values on column chart

Tags: python, charts, xlsxwriter, column-chart

Trying to rotate the `data_label` values on the chart to 90 degree since my chart is condensed and the values and overlapping.
I tried this but its not working, maybe because `'num_font':  {'rotation': 90}` is only for `set_x_axis`.

```
'data_labels': { 'value': True, 'position' : 'outside_end', 'num_font':  {'rotation': 90} }
```

Comment: Hrm, not working for me either.

Comment: The isn't currently possible. If you add a feature request issue on GitHub I'll add it.

Comment: Thank you @jmcnamara !  I created an issue here : https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/337

Comment: @jmcnamara, do you think this feature will be released soon? best regards!

Comment: This feature is available via the data label font property.

Comment: @jmcnamara Thank you so much! would you mind to add an answer with example for future seekers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `font` data label property can be used to rotate the data labels in a series:

```
 chart.add_series({
     'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5',
     'data_labels': {
         'value': True,
         'font': {'rotation': 45}
     },
 })
```